# MFC, OPENFILENAME structure: m_ofn.lpstrCustomFilter

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mfc

I'm just trying to figure out how to use `m_ofn.lpstrCustomFilter` in MFC's `CFileDialog`.

The internal structure is a `OPENFILENAME`.

I need a practical example, as all examples I have found are setting `lpstrCustomFilter` to NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`OPENFILENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) documentation:

> **lpstrCustomFilter**
>   Type: **LPTSTR**
>   A static buffer that contains a pair of null-terminated filter strings for preserving the filter pattern chosen by the user. The first string is your display string that describes the custom filter, and the second string is the filter pattern selected by the user. The first time your application creates the dialog box, you specify the first string, which can be any nonempty string. When the user selects a file, the dialog box copies the current filter pattern to the second string. The preserved filter pattern can be one of the patterns specified in the **lpstrFilter** buffer, or it can be a filter pattern typed by the user. The system uses the strings to initialize the user-defined file filter the next time the dialog box is created. If the **nFilterIndex** member is zero, the dialog box uses the custom filter.
>
> If this member is **NULL**, the dialog box does not preserve user-defined filter patterns.
>
> If this member is not **NULL**, the value of the **nMaxCustFilter** member must specify the size, in characters, of the **lpstrCustomFilter** buffer.
>
> **nMaxCustFilter**
>   Type: **DWORD**
>   The size, in characters, of the buffer identified by **lpstrCustomFilter**. This buffer should be at least 40 characters long. This member is ignored if **lpstrCustomFilter** is **NULL** or points to a **NULL** string.

For example:

```
TCHAR szfilter[256] = TEXT("custom filter\0*.ext\0");

...

m_ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = szFilter;
m_ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 256;
m_ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
```

The documentation implies that when the dialog is first shown and `nFilterIndex` is 0, the initial filter specified by `lpstrCustomFilter` is active, even if it is different than the filters specified by `lpstrFilter`.  If the user then selects/enters a different filter, `szfilter` is updated to contain the user's selected filter.  This allows you to save `szFilter` so that next time you display the dialog, you could initialize the dialog with the user's last selected filter, if desired.

And in practice, this works fine in XP and earlier.

In Windows 7 (and probably Vista) and later, `GetOpenFileName()` **DOES NOT** behave like this anymore, no matter how the `OPENFILENAME` is configured.  `GetOpenFileName()` simply ignores `lpstrCustomFilter`, never applies the initial custom filter, and never overwrites the `szFilter` buffer.  This implies that `lpstrCustomFilter` is now deprecated and no longer used, and setting `nFilterIndex=0` will silently be promoted to `nFilterIndex=1`.  Which might explain why all of the examples just set `lpstrCustomFilter` to `NULL`.

The reason for this change in behavior is because `GetOpenFileName()` is deprecated, it is now a wrapper for [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx) for backwards compatibility with legacy code.  `IFileOpenDialog` does not support preserving user-specified filters, it only works with application-defined filters.  There is no API in the newer dialog for setting or retrieving user-specified filters, so Microsoft clearly did not make the `GetOpenFileName()` wrapper try to simulate the old `lpstrCustomFilter` functionality within the newer dialog.

You could try to simulate the old `lpstrCustomFilter` behavior manually by using `lpstrFilter` instead.  Create an extra entry for `custom filter`. If the user has previously selected a file, initialize that entry with the selected file's extension, and set `nFilterIndex` to the 1-based index of that entry. Then, when the dialog is closed, extract the user's actual selected file extension using `lpstrFile` and `nFileExtension` and save it so you can initialize the `custom filter` entry later.

Comment: You made an amazing explanation. Thank you.